# Django - two form tags on single page with same action attribute

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

Ok, so I'm trying to make two form tags in single page separated by two different tabs within the page. I'm just wondering how I can process this.
I know if I use different action urls I can process them fine easily. But when there's a validation error, it goes to the url that form is being submitted to and I don't want that. I want it to stay inside the page which is why I'm making action=''.

**In HTML**

```
<!-----------template.html----------->
<div class=" tab">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <div class="card">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Info 1</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#groups" aria-controls="groups" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Info 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <!--Personal Info -->
    <div class="row tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="home">
        <!-- edit form column -->
        <div class="info1">
            {% include template1 %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="groups">
        <div class="info2">
            {% include template2 %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-----------template1----------->
<form method='post' action='' class="form-horizontal" role="form">
{%csrf_token%}
<input value=something>
<input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="{{formA.prefix}}">
</form>

<!-----------template2----------->
<form method='post' action='' class="form-horizontal" role="form">
{%csrf_token%}
<input value=something>
<input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="{{formA.prefix}}">
</form>
```

Here are the codes for an attempt at resolving this:

**VIEWS.PY**

```
def _get_form(request, form_class, prefix):
    data = request.POST if prefix in request.POST else None
    return form_class(data, prefix = prefix)
class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    login_url = '../login/'
    template_name = 'template.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.render_to_response({'formB':FormB(prefix='prefixA-'),'formB':FormB(prefix='prefixB-')})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formA = _get_form(request, FormA, 'payment-')
        formB = _get_form(request, FormB, 'user-')
        if formA.is_bound and formA.is_valid():
            # Do Something
        elif formB.is_bound and formB.is_valid():
            # Do Something
            # Update user
            obj = userForm.save(commit=False)
            logger.error(obj.first_name)
            obj.save()
        return self.render_to_response({'paymentForm':paymentForm, 'userForm':userForm})
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
class FormB(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [some fields]
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(FormB, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class FormA(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [some fields]
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(FormA, self).save(commit=False)
        return user
```

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong but the forms are either not getting submitted or .is_valid() fails and the form doesn't really do anything. Could anyone please please please help me solve this? 
Thank you!

Comment: How are you submitting the form(s)? Is the intention to submit both forms at the same time? Or one or the other?

Comment: it's one or the other. 
each of them have separate submit button too.
as a matter of fact, since formB is for updating user information, I was thinking about breaking them into several forms too. so when user clicks on edit button they can edit each field separately.

Comment: Hi John! This is a very solvable problem, don't worry! You can do anything with Django :) Is my understanding right that the crux of the issue is what URL you are being redirected to when the form is invalid? Does each form have it's own view that is separate from "MyView"? What view is being returned instead when they are invalid? (BTW, if you don't already have it installed, get django-debug-toolbar which can help with debugging views.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to fix all your issues by only cleaning the code:

1. Your second form has wrong prefix.

   ```
   <!-----------template1----------->
   <form method='post' action='' class="form-horizontal" role="form">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ formA }}
   <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="{{ formA.prefix }}">
   </form>

   <!-----------template2----------->
   <form method='post' action='' class="form-horizontal" role="form">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ formB }}
   <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="{{ formB.prefix }}">
   </form>
   ```
2. `get()` has wrong prefixes too

   ```
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       return self.render_to_response({
           'formA': FormA(prefix='prefixA-'),
           'formB': FormB(prefix='prefixB-')
       })
   ```
3. `post()` has wrong prefixes and variable names:

   ```
   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       formA = _get_form(request, FormA, 'prefixA-')
       formB = _get_form(request, FormB, 'prefixB-')
       if formA.is_bound and formA.is_valid():
           # Do Something
       elif formB.is_bound and formB.is_valid():
           # Do Something
           # Update user
           obj = formB.save(commit=False)
           logger.error(obj.first_name)
           obj.save()

       return self.render_to_response({
           'formA': formA,
           'formB': formB
       })
   ```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms